# How to Dockerise Windows Based UI Application Test Cases

Tags: python, windows, docker, automation

So, we have a windows UI based application, and we run a python script to automate the testing for that UI based application on windows OS.

Now is it possible to dockerise windows OS and whenever we hit docker run command the automation script should trigger and run it?

We have multiple automation scripts for that same UI based application but with different network configuration on windows 10, but is it possible to have a multiple docker image for all the scripts? Meaning everything we just run a docker image instead of changing network configuration and setup on windows 10 manually. Lot of time we do face errors and blockers in the automation script. is there a way to optimize this manual process to make it less cumbersome using docker?

The problem is that windows 10 vm cannot run on docker, and our application is UI based dependent on the windows 10 OS,  and the automation script is in such a way that it loads up the UI application on the screen and tests different test cases. If only there was a way to dockerise windows 10 OS and have a setup running in that docker image that would be awesome.

Comment: That sounds like you need a virtual machine.  I don't know if it's possible to run Windows GUI applications in containers at all; certainly a container doesn't run a full OS.

Comment: yes, I understand that docker container runs on a single kernel, but I'm trying to automate the process which we run on windows VM. Is it even remotely possible with any work around or tweaks?